# Cannot copy files to an Android phone via MTP due to "operation not supported"

Tags: usb, nautilus, android, samsung, mtp

I'm trying to copy some music files from a file server to the internal memory card of my Samsung phone.

When I plug the phone in I can access the memory card via MTP in Nautilus just fine. However, when I try to copy any file I just get "operation not supported".

It still seems to be able to create new **folders**, but not files.

I'm pretty sure this has previously worked with other Ubuntu-Android-combination. What seems to be the problem here?

Samsung Galaxy A52s (Android 14) and Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Comment: [This link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1489434/how-do-i-connect-my-android-smartphone-to-my-pc-through-usb-and-transfer-files/1489478#1489478) may help you solve the problem. The command line tool `gio` might help, if the graphical tools do not work,

Comment: When I use Android, and plug in the phone with USB to the computer, I pick the "File Transfer" option and it works fine.

Comment: You could try `adb push /path/to/file.mp3 /sdcard` (sdcard means internal storage) instead, after installing adb on Ubuntu and enabling USB debugging on the phone

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Yeah, that's how it's supposed to work, but it doesn't.

Comment: @juzzlin I noticed USB debugging options on Android 13 are kind of buried and not intuitive in Settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason seemed to be the fact that Nautilus or Android didn't allow directly copying files from the file server to the memory card via MTP. When I first copied the files to a local directory and then copied these files to the phone, it worked. So, apparently this was the operation that was not supported.

Note, that if I copy files from my file server to a regular USB stick or USB drive it works without any problems. Not sure what the actual **technical problem** is in this particular case.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution/workaround :-)